# How can a nameserver block Google bot?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, google, googlebot

Background: Our domain `page.et` is not accessible by Google's [mobile-friendly checking tool](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly/result?id=Ons-JWZgpK0eSVb3DFKK8Q) and search console. The same seems to be true for all other `.et` domains I tested.

The reason is not the robots.txt. Google bot does not even try to make a connection to the server (verified via `tcpdump`)

I want to understand the technical background of the following [answer to another user with a similar / same problem:](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/121050229/problem-with-indexation-with-all-domains-in-et-zone-Problem-with-indexing-all-domains-et?hl=en&msgid=123891296)

(From Russian via Google Translate)

> Hello Alexander !
> At the moment, I only learned that the problem is on the side of the .et nameservers  -  they "block" Googlebot
> Accordingly, neither you nor Google, at the moment, have the opportunity to directly influence the solution of this issue.
> Google specialists are trying to contact representatives of NS  .et  to resolve the current situation
> Unfortunately, there are no guarantees / messages about the time when this issue will be resolved.

So how can a nameserver / zone "block" a Google bot?
And how can such a block be verified?

The domain can be resolved by Google's own nameserver 8.8.8.8 (verified by `dig page.et @8.8.8.8`) and I would believe, that the Google bot uses the same nameserver

---

Remark: I also [posted in the Webmasters Google Support forum](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/142632230/page-et-cannot-be-submitted-to-google-ethiopian-domains-blocked-in-general?hl=en) but here I would like to understand the technical background how a name server can block Google bot or any other HTTP client from accessing a site.

Answer (score 1):

Putting it simply, Google or any other name servers are going to have to recurse to .et nameservers in order to access any information in them; if they collectively block Google, then any URL-based requests will fail, as name resolution will fail.

This is an overly simplistic answer of how, but it’s possible.

Comment: Interesting part is the 8.8.8.8 nameserver is not blocked. How does the Google bot resolve domain names?